# Parse jq array iterate and search string regex

Tags: arrays, bash, jq

I am working with a JSON below:

```
{
    "CITY": "JANCOK NJARAN",
    "FATHER": {
        "1": "WEDHUS",
        "2": "ANDRE"
    },
    "MOTHER": {
        "11": "SARAH",
        "22": "EVELYN",
        "33": "MARKONAH"
    }
}
```

I parse it with jq to read json

```
file=$(cat config.json)
city=$(echo $file | ./jq '.CITY')
father=$(echo $base_config | ./jq '.FATHER[]')
```

I have `$data` :

```
HE IS WEDHUS FROM JANCOK NJARAN, ALSO MARKONAH
```

For now i have a lot of problem, i know how to do it with php, but dont know how to do it with bash

what i want is parse the json using `jq` and search string inside `$data` with json provided

Expected output is like this.

```
Search in $data with JSON config :
Found WEDHUS with id 1 , and MARKONAH with id 2
```

Any help will be appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not completely sure what you are trying to achieve, but this might help you on the way there:

Traverse the input document using `..`, and decompose the `objects` found into an array of key-value pairs using `to_entries`. Then, filter it by iterating `.[]` over its items, and `select`ing only those whose `.value`, if in turn being `strings`, is completely contained `inside` the `$data` string, which was provided as argument using the `--arg` option on invocation). The remaining items can then be formatted to your liking, here using string interpolation `\(…)` to produce strings, and the `-r` option on invocation to output them in raw format (as opposed to being JSON encoded).

```bash
jq -r --arg data "$data" '
  .. | objects | to_entries[]
  | select(.value | strings | inside($data))
  | "Found \(.value) with id \(.key)"
' config.json
```

```
Found JANCOK NJARAN with id CITY
Found WEDHUS with id 1
Found MARKONAH with id 33
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/wY0bY82HRUB)

If you want to disregard the top level (eg. `CITY`), prepend `..` with `.[] |`.

To just output a comma-separated list consisting only of all the matching IDs, wrap the whole traversal, filtering, and formatting into a pair of brackets `[…]` turning the whole result stream into an array, then use `join` with a glue string to concatenate. Additional formatting such as wrapping the final list within parentheses can also be done here, eg. using again string interpolation.

```bash
jq -r --arg data "$data" '
  [ .. | objects | to_entries[]
  | select(.value | strings | inside($data)).key
  ] | "(\(join(",")))"
' config.json
```

```
(CITY,1,33)
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/DLc8w6vvfmN)

Comment: thanks brother, this is great answer, my fool i cant explain what i want to achieve.
this is what i want, many many big thanks

Comment: how i can show output with coma delimiter. 

id only, 

output will like this (CITY,1,33)

,,,, i use `"\(.key)" | join(",")` but show Cannot iterate over string

Comment: also can you explain to me what is that code one by one